# Python Selenium XPATH with multiple tags

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, webdriver, xpath-1.0

I have an automated python script to check for any changes in the DOM. I have a xpath that works:

```
//td[@class='high-bg']/a[@class='link-action'][@data-hintbox='1'][@data-hintbox-static='1'][@role='button'][@href='javascript:void(0)']
```

But it gives me more outputs than I need and some of them cause errors. So i want to get the abstract items that i need from an xpath, so I'm trying to use something like this:

```
//table[@id't5c711109b1eea263276674']/tbody[]/tr[]/td[@class='warning-bg']/a[@class='link-action'][@data-hintbox='1'][@data-hintbox-static='1'][@role='button'][@href='javascript:void(0)']
```

But it's not working, so is it even possible to search xpath with that many tags?

[image]

```
<table id="example">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="average-bg">
                <a class="link-action" data-hintbox="1" data-hintbox-static="1" role="button"                   href="javascript:void(0)">1</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you please replace html image with html in text format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

About your code trials:

- In your first attempt you have tried to use all the attributes of the element to construct the *xpath*:

  ```
  //td[@class='high-bg']/a[@class='link-action'][@data-hintbox='1'][@data-hintbox-static='1'][@role='button'][@href='javascript:void(0)']
  ```
- Elements with similar attributes can be present but at different position/location. Hence it returns more than desired outputs you need.
- In your second attempt you have constructed an *absolute* xpath which is *brittle*:

  ```
  //table[@id't5c711109b1eea263276674']/tbody[]/tr[]/td[@class='warning-bg']/a[@class='link-action'][@data-hintbox='1'][@data-hintbox-static='1'][@role='button'][@href='javascript:void(0)']
  ```

---

### Solution

As per the text based HTML you have provided, to identify the desired element you can use either of the following solutions:

- `xpath`:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table[@id='example']//td[@class='average-bg']/a[@class='link-action' and text()='1']")
  ```
- `css_selector`:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("table#example td.average-bg>a.link-action")
  ```

Comment: Thank you! i found another way around it, but you cleared up some things for me, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Here it is.

XML

```
<root>
  <e1 role='a' class='y'></e1>
  <e1 role='a' class='t'></e1>
  <e1 role='a' class='z'></e1>
</root>
```

XAPTH

```
//e1[@role='a' and @class='t']
```

Output

```
Element='<e1 class="t" role="a"/>'
```

Comment: Yes i get that much, thank you. But what if there was a table in your root, could i navigate toward my needed element somehow ? if its really deep inside

Comment: I think you can. Why not?

Comment: lets say my element was in e1 element,  how would i represent this in my xpath ?